# Woo Commerce, remove columns completely in archive

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to using woocommerce and only been working with wordpress about six months so may be an easy answer.

I don't want any columns in my archive at all. I just want to display the products using a responsive grid system like this ...

http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/

or use masonry (preferred).

I have used masonry in a page template in wordpress to display an unordered list before without a problem but cannot figure out how to use it or the responsive grid with woocommerce shop.

How can I stop woocommerce using columns ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried overriding the template?

Comment: I know how to override (child-theme ?), but I am not sure how you would code it on the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding can be done in various ways, here's the cleanest approach:

The file is located at `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php`. You should put it in your theme folder - `wp-content/themes/woocommerce/archive-product.php`. Then make the changes you want. For instance, I'd start with removing the line `do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' )`. You might also want to override `wrapper-start.php` and `wrapper-end.php` found in the templates folder ( in either `shop` or `global` subfolder, depending on woocommerce version ), which can be overriden exactly the same way.

For reference, see their documentation: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: It is th wordpress/woocommerce code for each item on the archive I am getting confused with I think.  I need to work out where the <li> lags would go and in which template.  The <ul> tag is on the loop-start file.

Comment: have a look at content-product_cat.php

Comment: Found them. OK will have a play with that.Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

MSTAnnu put me on the right lines, I needed to be using content-product.php, and added a class to the

tag in there. This overrides all column issues.

I changed the  tag in the loop-start.php file in templates/global and used css to style into a responsive design using %. Not used to masonry layout yet but if I do will add solution here unless someone beats me to it.